# R doesn't read/run the entire matrix

Tags: r

The code stops working after it reads six numbers, for some reason, and we want it to read it entirely.

```
tabela <- read.table("C:/Users/pedro/OneDrive/Ambiente de Trabalho/hicp.csv", sep = ';', header = T)
tabela_poultry = tabela[c(5, 34, 63, 92, 121, 150, 179, 208, 237, 266, 295, 324, 353), 3]
head(tabela_poultry)
```

The variable tabela is taken from a excel sheet, and the column important to us is the third, where the values are stored.

We've tried dividing it into different variables and then concatenating it, and it sorta works, but instead the values it gives us are all scrabled together.

Comment: The `head()` function returns the first six values of a vector or the first six rows of a two-dimensional object. Your code is doing exactly what you tell it to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an error.

Comment: Impossible to tell without your csv file